# Word/Idiom for 'one bad experience not ruining it for future encounters'

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I'm looking for a word or idiom that helps describe the scenario where though you have had one bad experience with something it has not spoiled your view on that thing. Example:

> I had a bad experience working in services but that doesn't mean all services jobs are bad.

Comment: Could you please tell us more about the connotations you'd like the word or phrase to bring, and a dialogue in which you'd like to use it?  There are too many possibilities as your question stands.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the word ***aberration***. It implies a departure from the usual, and in your context, you want to say that you are *not swayed by aberrations*.

> I had a bad experience working in services but *I hope that's just an **aberration***.

ODO:

> **[aberration](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/aberration)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> **1** A departure from what is normal, usual, or expected, typically an unwelcome one:
>   ‘they described the outbreak of violence in the
>   area as an aberration’
>
> ‘Despite aberrations, we are still a by and large secular state.’
>
> ‘Mee added, ‘Although I do not know who is responsible for these
>   incidents I hope that they were aberrations and shall not be seen
>   again.’’

Answer (score 0):

***[One bad apple doesn't spoil the whole bunch](https://www.google.it/search?q=one%20bad%20apple%20doesn%27t%20spoil%20the%20bunch&rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT606IT607&hl=it&prmd=ivsn&ei=D8NGWJb_MMGxUdjuoNAD&start=10&sa=N&biw=1024&bih=653)*** :

- an idiomatic expression that is used to refer to situations where a mistake or a wrong is not expected to compromise the whole context.

Comment: Those results seem to demonstrate that the *idiom* is 'one bad apple **spoils** the whole bunch/barrel' and that 'doesn't spoil' version exists as a refutation of it. When storing apples it's important not to put up  damaged ones because they speed up the decay of the rest. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bad+apple+spoils%2C+bad+apple+doesn%27t+spoil&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbad%20apple%20spoils%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbad%20apple%20does%20not%20spoil%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 0):

Your bad experience could be described as *atypical*, or, especially if you have a statistically-minded audience, an *outlier*.

*atypical* (adj): not representative of a type, group, or class

*outlier* (n): a person or thing differing from all other members of a particular group or set